# Why is Cron job ignoring timeout specified with init_set?

Tags: php, cron

I'm using https://cron-job.org/ for a cron job but I have a problem. When running the script manually (for example, a script that gets data from a csv file), it works but if I run the script through that cron job, it fails because of that 30 seconds max_execution_time I guess.

But the problem is that in my script I'm already using:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

It should be 5 minutes instead of 30 seconds before the cron job fails. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an image with that cron job history:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cron-job.org has some limits:

> **How and how long does cron-job.org visit my URLs?**
>   cron-job.org visits your URLs at the configured dates/intervals and waits for the URL/script to finish execution. **If your URL/script does not finish after 30 seconds, it will timeout and we will close the connection** to prevent delays in the execution of the jobs of other users. Our system reads up to 1024 bytes of the output of your URLs/scripts. In case your script sends more data, job execution will be aborted. (Please also see the next question.)

You can read more here: [FAQ](https://cron-job.org/en/faq/).

Comment: i hate cron-job.org now :D